# Difference in hours between 2 particular days - PHP

Tags: php

I have two date objects say 10/01/2016 00:00:00 to 18/01/2016 08:00:00. I want to check whether these 2 dates lies between friday 12 AM to Sunday 12 Am then how to find difference in hours ?

PHP code -

```
$t1 = StrToTime($date2);
$t2 = StrToTime($date1);
$diff = $t1-$t2;

$hours = abs($diff / ( 60 * 60 ));
```

I am badly stuck in this. Please someone help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Update your post with the [mcve] PHP code.

Comment: updated @PraveenKumar..

Comment: The `strtotime` should be all small right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar [It's not *required*, but it does look way prettier in lowercase letters](https://eval.in/536130).

Comment: no.. not accessary.. @PraveenKumar

Comment: Not necessary, but you still shouldn't RandOMizE CApiTalIZAtioN...

Comment: Ha ha okay @deceze ... `:)` But the code looks alright for me. What does the two date variables contain?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ That's the same code the OP has given, which is not working.

Comment: @PraveenKumar two date  value like 12/01/2015 00:02:05

Comment: @JayeshBarot As a string?

Comment: yes @PraveenKumar as a string

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to test if the date is either a friday or a saturday, with no relevance how far they are away from each other.

You can use the [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function of the DateTime object to get the weekday of the date, then test if it is a friday (5) or a saturday (6):

```
$t1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "10/01/2016 00:00:00");
$t2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "18/01/2016 08:00:00");

function testDate($date) {
    $d = $date->format("N");
    if ($d == 5) return true;
    if ($d == 6) return true;
    return false;
}

$d1 = testDate($t1);
$d2 = testDate($t2);

var_dump($d1, $d2);

// Result:
// bool(false)
// bool(false)
```

Then you can use the [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function to get the difference:

```
$diff = $t1->diff($t2);
var_dump($diff);
```

Result:

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(8)
  ["h"]=>
  int(8)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(8)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

So, 8 days (`$diff['days']`) and 8 hours (`$diff['h']`)

Comment: how much hours   dates in between Friday 12Am TO Sunday 12 Am

Comment: See my edit for the difference.

Comment: suppose my two date  is 13/03/2016  11 Am to 14/03/2016 12 AM so  between Friday 12Am To Sunday  12 AM      i get 1 hours result  ...

Comment: @JayeshBarot I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$date1 = "2016-08-14 00:00:00"; //more higger day
$date2 = "2016-08-13 00:00:00";    
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)); 

$years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
$months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
$days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));    
$hours   = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60));     
$minuts  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60);     
$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60)); 

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minuts\n, %d seconds\n", $years, $months, $days, $hours, $minuts, $seconds);
```

Output: 0 years, 0 months, 1 days, 0 hours, 0 minuts , 0 seconds

Now, you can do:

```
$date1 = "2016-08-14 00:00:00"; //more higger day
$date2 = "2016-08-13 00:00:00";    
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)); 

$years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
$months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
$days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));    
$hours   = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60));   

echo "Totals hours: ".($days*24 + $hours);
```

Returns 24 (and you can multiply the years, months and so on)

Comment: i want to  check $diff    in  between Friday 12AM TO Sunday 12AM

Comment: suppose my two date is 13/03/2016 11 Am to 14/03/2016 12 AM so between Friday 12Am To Sunday 12 AM i get 1 hours result